# Modal Can't Be Opened When Page is Not Reloaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

After submitting data, page is not reloaded, it's on purpose. In this state, modal can't be opened every time I want to open it. But if I reload the page, modal can be opened, sometimes can be opened and immediately close. Help me... I don't get any message error. It's very very confusing...

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" data-modal="ajaxModelForCreate"
            data-target="#ajaxModelForCreate" data-toggle="modal" style="margin-top:25px;" id="createNewProduct">
            Create
            New
            Product</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModelForCreate" aria-hidden="true"></div>

$('#createNewProduct').on('click', function() {
        $('#saveBtnForCreate').val("create-product");
        $('#product_idForCreate').val('');
        $('#modelHeadingForCreate').html("Create New Product");
        var idModal = $(this).data("modal");
        $(idModal).modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: Not sure what might be issue . But , here `$(idModal).modal('show');` you are missing `#` i.e : `$("#"+idModal).modal('show')` . Also , this line is not needed because you already have `data-target="#ajaxModelForCreate"` .

Comment: Hi again, @Swati.. Thank you very much for your response. It's still can't be opened... Closes immediately after opened. The behavior of modal is strange, it's not smooth...

Comment: Can you replicate that behaviour by creating working demo code ?

Comment: I dont know how to do that... Seems, it's hard enough.  If you dont mind, we can connect via TeamViewer. Or, I will push it to GitHub. What do you say?

Comment: Just add that page to pastebin or send me github link for that page i will check that afterward :)

Comment: Ok. Wait a sec. I'll do it in GitHub...

Comment: https://github.com/saadabdurrazaq/eureka
Let's check it out. You can find the error by trying input new product, after the data is inputted, push the button "Create New Product" again, and you will see the modal is open, and then closes immediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231867/discussion-between-swati-and-sead-lab).